# Using React Native Linking with Redux - accessing dispatch

Tags: api, react-native, redux, deep-linking

I'm working on a React Native app which is connecting to the Instagram API. I am going through the process of exchanging the OAuth token for an access token which is needed for the Instagram API, and the final step is to save the access token to the database, which I believe is best done using Redux via a dispatch function.

Here's my code:

Component:

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Connect to Instagram</Text>
            <Button
                onPress={this.props.authUserInstagram}
                title={'Connect to Instagram'}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Social.service.js:

```
export const authUserInstagram = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        return SocialApi.authUser()
            .then(response => {
                SafariView.show({
                    url: response.url,
                    fromBottom: true
                });
                Linking.addEventListener('url', handleUrl);
            })
        };
};

const handleUrl = event => {
    //remove listener here as it makes sense rather than doing it in component
    Linking.removeEventListener('url', handleUrl);
    var url = new URL(event.url);
    const code = url.searchParams.get('token');
    const error = url.searchParams.get('error');
    SafariView.dismiss();
    //I wish to access dispatch here to save the token in the state
};
```

I do get the access token back, which is great. The app is opened from the SafariView because my node server redirects the user back to the app using deep linking (which is what the Linking library is used for - part of React Native). But I have 2 questions:

1. Is it ok that I'm using the React Native Linking feature inside my social service? All examples I see online are with the Linking being used in the component.
2. I can't access the dispatch function in the handleUrl() function, which I assume is needed to send the Instagram token to the state to comply with Redux. What is the best way to access dispatch here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. I am not seeing any problem here, but rather than implementing on your own, you should look this [repo](https://github.com/watzak/react-native-instagram-oauth) on github, or you can find more repositories available on Git hub.
2. In order to access dispatch anywhere, you can map dispatch to props.

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import LoginActions, { loggedInUser } from '../Redux/LoginRedux'

        type SignupScreenProps = {
         attemptSignup: () => void,
}

class SignupScreen extends React.Component {

props: SignupScreenProps
           
// your component logic

const handleUrl = event => {
    //remove listener here as it makes sense rather than doing it in component
    Linking.removeEventListener('url', handleUrl);
    var url = new URL(event.url);
    const code = url.searchParams.get('token');
    const error = url.searchParams.get('error');
    SafariView.dismiss();
    //this is how you can access.
    this.props.attemptSignup();
};

render() {
//button view

<Button
  onPress={this.props.authUserInstagram}
  title={'Connect to Instagram'}
/>
}

}

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
//access redux store here
return {
        dara.state
      }
    }

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
        return {
          attemptSignup: (name, email, birthday, gender, avatar, password) => dispatch(LoginActions.signupRequest(name, email, birthday, gender, avatar, password))
        }
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SignupScreen)
```

See if it helps. Let me know.